# Dict whith 'list' of 'values' from of two different 'dicts', using a 'dict-comprehension' and 'for in' and 'if'

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

For example, two dictionaries are given:  NEED and DG.

It is required to create a new 'dict' (NDE), in which the new 'keys' will be the same as in NEED, and the new 'values' (NDE) will correspond to the 'list' with the nested DG dictionary, the 'keys' of which correspond to the 'value' in (NEED), and 'values' - 'values'  from DG.

```
In: NEED=  {'need1': ['good1', 'good2'], 'need2': ['good2']}
    DG= {'good1': '20', 'good2': '15'}

Out: NDE={'need1':[{'good1': '20', 'good2': '15'}], 'need2': [{'good2': '15'}]}
```

Comment: alright, but what is your specific, programming-related _question_? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I just started to learn python, I'm trying to master the dict-comprehension method.
I can create simple dictionaries, but complex ones are not yet.
For example, such a code - I write:
More complex - I'm still learning.
    MY_T = {'f': [10, 20, 30], 'o': 12, 'b': 33}
    MY_DT = {x: y for (x, y) in zip (MY_T.keys (), MY_T.values ())}
    print (MY_DT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When attempting to use list or dict comprehension, I typically try to solve the problem using a normal `for loop` since the logic tends to be a little more straightforward. In this case, the series of loops would look like:

```
NEED = {'need1': ['good1', 'good2'], 'need2': ['good2']}
DG = {'good1': '20', 'good2': '15'}

NDE = {}
for need_key, need_list in NEED.items():
    sub_dict = {}
    for need_child_key in need_list:
        sub_dict[need_child_key] = DG[need_child_key]

    NDE[need_key] = [sub_dict]
```

Once I have it working without comprehension, I start tackling the comprehension component.

```
NDE = {
    need_key: [
        {need_child_key: DG[need_child_key] for need_child_key in need_list}
    ] 
    for need_key, need_list in NEED.items()
}
```

Note: My solution assumes that the values in NEED will always correspond to keys in DG...

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been fighting this task all day and using the dict-comprehension method.You really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

```
NEED = {'need1': ['good1', 'good2'], 'need2': ['good2']}
DG = {'good1': '20', 'good2': '15'}

NDE={}
for i in NEED.keys(): #initializing nested dict
    NDE[i] = {}

for i in NEED.keys():
    for j in DG.keys():
        for k in NEED[i]:
            if k==j:
                NDE[i][j] = DG[j]

print(NDE)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'need1': {'good1': '20', 'good2': '15'}, 'need2': {'good2': '15'}}
```